# How to catch errors from two requests in one place using RxSwift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, rx-swift

I'm quite new and I'm wondering how to catch error from requests which are zipped (see snipped above) in one place. In current implementation I have error handling in two places, but my goal is to have it in one place. My requests are zipped because if one of this req gets failed whole sequence will fail so in result I want to have one error handling place in code for both request.

```
 let firstReq =  self.sendReq() // returns  Observable<Bool>
        .catchError {
            error in
            return self.just(true)
    }

    let secondReq =  self.sendReqTwo() // returns  Observable<Bool>
        .catchError {
            error in
            return self.just(true)
    }


    goBttnOutlet.rx_tap
        .subscribeNext {
          Observable.zip(firstReqRes, secondReqRes) { (firstRes, secondRes) -> Bool in
                return firstRes && secondRes
            }.subscribeNext { summaryRes in
                print(" \(summaryRes)")
            }.addDisposableTo(self.rx_disposableBag)
        }.addDisposableTo(rx_disposableBag)
```

..maybe some link with example code with handling error in common place will be great for me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` returns a new `Observable<T>`, so you can simply move the `catchError` operator application to what `zip` returns.

```
let firstReq =  self.sendReq()
let secondReq =  self.sendReqTwo()
let zippedReq = Observable.zip(firstReq, secondReq)
    .catchErrorJustReturn { _ in true }

goBttnOutlet.rx_tap
    .subscribeNext {
      zippedReq.subscribeNext { summaryRes in
            print(" \(summaryRes)")
        }.addDisposableTo(self.rx_disposableBag)
    }.addDisposableTo(rx_disposableBag)
```

---

On a side note, you could improve the chain after goBttnOutlet to the following

```
goBttnOutlet.rx_tap.flatMap { zippedReq }
    .subscribeNext { summaryRes in
        print(" \(summaryRes)")
    }.addDisposableTo(rx_disposableBag)
```

See [flatMap documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) for details.